# Finding highest values in a data frame per category in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 3 columns: category, brand, and total count of orders made per brand in a specific category:

```
  X2            X1        total.count
Accessories    3MT          2098
Accessories    A82          1834
Accessories    A14           109
Tops           A79            87
Tops           A74           435
```

I have 150 different categories and 1700 different brands.

I want to create a data frame with the category, the most ordered brand in that category, and the number of orders for that brand. So far, I used subsetting to retrieve the top brand in each category, but I could only figure how to do it one by one:

```
b1 <- subset (DF, X2 == "Accessories")
b1$total.count<- sort(b1$total.count, decreasing = TRUE)
```

From there I took the first row:

```
s1 = head(b1, n=1)
```

I had to do this for each category, and then bound them all together into one data frame:

```
topbrands = data.frame(rbind(head(b1,n = 
1),head(b2,n=1),head(b3,n=1),head(b4, n=1),head(b5,n=1)....
```

all the way until b150.
Is there a sleeker or more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

---

dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(X2) %>% filter(total.count==max(total.count)) %>% as.data.frame
```

---

Or with data.table:

```
dt = data.table(df)
dt[ , .SD[which.max(total.count)], by = X2]
```

---

output:

```
           X2  X1 total.count
1 Accessories 3MT        2098
2        Tops A74         435
```

Answer (score 1):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df,df$X2), function(x) {return(x[which.max(x$total.count),])}))
```

Check if this helps!